# Firebase - can't build two different listviews for different tabviews

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am building an application that has a tabview with two different tabs for lost items and found items. I am using Firebase as my Database and populate the listviews with two seperate FirebaseListAdapters. The fist listview for the lost items in the first tab loads and displays just fine. When I try to load the second tab, my app crashes with the following error:

> E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type lostandfound.mi.ur.de.lostandfound.FoundItem

These are some of my code snippets I am using:
        **MainActivity:**

```
      private void getFireBaseLostData() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference lostRef = ref.child("LostItem");


        FirebaseListAdapter<LostItem> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<LostItem>(this, LostItem.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, lostRef) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, LostItem model, int position) {
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
                ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getDescription());
            }
        };
        lostListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

This is the corresponding item:

    public class LostItem {
    private String name;
    private String date;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private String category;
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String town;
    private String contact;

    public LostItem(String name, String date, double longitude, double latitude, String category, String description, String town, String contact){
        this.name=name;
        this.date=date;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.category=category;
        this.description = description;
        this.town = town;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public LostItem(){
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){this.description = description;}
    public String getDescription(){return description;}

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getDate() {return date;}
    public double getLongitude() {return longitude;}
    public double getLatitude() {return longitude;}
    public String getCategory() {return category;}
    public String getContact() {return contact;}
    public String getTown() {return town;}
    public int getId() {return id;}

}
```

Here is the part which crashes my app - it's basically the same.:        **MainActivity:**

```
   private void getFireBaseFoundData() {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference foundRef = ref.child("FoundItem");

    FirebaseListAdapter<FoundItem> foundItemFirebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<FoundItem>(this, FoundItem.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, foundRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, FoundItem model, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getDescription());
        }
    };
    foundListView.setAdapter(foundItemFirebaseListAdapter);
}
```

**And the FoundItem:**

```
  public class FoundItem {

    private String name;
    private String date;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;
    private String category;
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String town;
    private String contact;

    public FoundItem(String name, String date, double longitude, double latitude, String category, String description, String town, String contact){
        this.name=name;
        this.date=date;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.category=category;
        this.description = description;
        this.town = town;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public FoundItem(){
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setTown(String town) {
        this.town = town;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){this.description = description;}
    public String getDescription(){return description;}

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getDate() {return date;}
    public double getLongitude() {return longitude;}
    public double getLatitude() {return longitude;}
    public String getCategory() {return category;}
    public String getContact() {return contact;}
    public String getTown() {return town;}
    public int getId() {return id;}

}
```

JSON tree:

```
{"FoundItem" : {
"-KSDsf6YVBBbSBHw7vID" : {
  "category" : "Einen runden Hut",
  "contact" : "Gar nicht ohne meinen Hut!",
  "date" : "21.09.16",
  "description" : "Es ist ein Hut",
  "id" : 0,
  "latitude" : 0.0,
  "longitude" : 0.0,
  "name" : "Hut",
  "town" : "Regensburg"
}
},
 "LostItem" : {
"-KSD_MKYWmLUbUyW0KYn" : {
  "category" : "ein iphone suche ich",
  "contact" : "gar nicht",
  "date" : "21.09.16",
  "description" : "gib mir mein iphone!",
  "id" : 0,
  "latitude" : 0.0,
  "longitude" : 0.0,
  "name" : "iphone",
  "town" : "Regensburg"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your json tree?/

Comment: It's in the first post now.

Comment: please share the json tree image from firebase console, its not clear

Comment: I don't know why or how but it seems to be working just fine as of now. I did not change anything. Oh well, let's hope it stays that way. Thanks for your help though! :)